# SFML built from CMake doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sfml

I've successfully built SFML from github with static linkage for libraries and against runtime (the one downloaded from website is dynamically linked against runtime, which requires users to have msvcrXXX.dll installed when used with Visual Studio). It works fine and all, until I start using my code.

The problem is `sf::RenderWindow::draw`, when called with something like `sf::RectangleShape` it works no problem and displays nice colored rectangle. However, when I start using my own class for this, it pops an error.

The class hierarchy:

There is a base class as follows:

```
class ButtonBase : public sf::Drawable{
public:
    virtual ~ButtonBase() {}
    virtual void callback(ButtonClickState) = 0;
    virtual void onHover(HoverState) = 0;
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget&, sf::RenderStates) const = 0;
    virtual sf::Sprite& getBackground() const = 0;
    virtual LabelBase& getLabel() const = 0;
    virtual TooltipBase& getTooltip() const = 0;
    virtual void hide() = 0;
    virtual void show() = 0;
    virtual bool isHidden() const = 0;
    virtual int getZ() const = 0;
    virtual void setZ(int) = 0;
};
```

As you can see, this class inherits sf::Drawable so all Buttons that inherit ButtonBase can be used in a way: `window.draw(buttonInstance);`.

The Button looks roughly as this:

```
class Button final : public ButtonBase{
    mutable Label label;
    sf::Texture texture;
    mutable sf::Sprite buttonImage;
    mutable int z;
    bool active;
public:
    //constructors, destructors, whatnot

    void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
    {
        if (active)
        {
            target.draw(buttonImage, states);
            target.draw(label, states);
            //target.draw(bTltp, states);
        }
    }

    //more stuff
};
```

Most stuff is irrelevant. I boiled the problem down to when I call the draw inside `Button` after the function returns/goes out of scope, this error is popped:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.

I am using the default one: cdecl convention. Is SFML build with SFML_LINK_STD_STATICALLY (or whatever is that flag in CMake called) to true using some weird/other convention?

To note, I have defined SFML_STATIC flag in preprocessor macros, and I am using correct (debug with debug, normal with release build) libs.

I am very sure that this code will work with dynamically linked library downloaded from the official website, because I have made whole project which fully worked.

Comment: In order to fully understand the problem, you need to provide a complete and minimal example (= one file, directly compilable). The error you've provided usually occurs with dynamic libraries. Did you set `SFML_USE_STATIC_STD_LIBS` to true? How do you link against the runtime libraries?

Comment: I set that flag to true, I set the BUILD_SHARED_LIBS to false. I linked against the runtime using /MT and /MTd for debug version

Comment: Still misses a minimal and complete example. Did you take [this](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/FAQ#build-link-static) into account?